# How many quotas does one search request use on the Youtube API V3?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I remember reading somewhere that each search request takes 100 quotas, but I can't find where i read this. I looked into my Daily Quota limit and it says I've use 6000 of the free 10,000 per day, but i have not made 6000 search requests today. Not even close to 100 requests. Could anyone confirm the number of quotas it takes please?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#pageInfo.totalResults#overview states 100 of quota use per Search: list endpoint request.

Comment: Thanks, I coudln't remember where that was.